Passing encrypted string as nsdata in http body gives 400 bad request error
I am encrypting a json string and then converting it into NSData and trying to pass it as http body as per standard but it gives me sever error as 400 bad request whereas it works perfectly as expected in postman.
But failing I guess at iOS end , can someone highlight what could be wrong?
Check below code for reference :
NSData *datas = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:paramsDic options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString *jsonStrings = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:datas encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *jencWithPubKey = [EncryptionAlgorithm encryptString:jsonStrings publicKey:APP_PUBLIC_KEY2];
NSData *data1 = [jencWithPubKey dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Value of json string %@", jencWithPubKey);

NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:QMMemberLogin]];
NSDictionary *heads =@{@"User-Agent":@"Apifox/1.0.0(https://apifox.com)",
                       @"Content-Type":@"appliction/json; charset=UTF-8",
                       @"Accept":@"*/*",
                       @"Conection":@"keep-alive"};
[urlRequest setAllHTTPHeaderFields:heads];

//Apply the data to the body
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:data1];

//create the Method "GET" or "POST"
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];



NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    if(httpResponse.statusCode == 200)
    {
        NSError *parseError = nil;
        NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
        NSLog(@"The response is - %@",responseDictionary);
        NSInteger success = [[responseDictionary objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue];
        if(success == 1)
        {
            NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Login FAILURE");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }
}];
[dataTask resume];

Above code I have tried in objective C

May i know, what kind of information holding in nsdata

NSDictionary converted into nsdata  and then nsdata converted to json string like below :
NSMutableDictionary *paramsDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[paramsDic setValue:@"testTrial@5." forKey:@"password"];
[paramsDic setValue:@"9123456789" forKey:@"loginId"];
[paramsDic setValue:@"Mobile" forKey:@"loginType"];
[paramsDic setValue:@"91" forKey:@"phoneCode"];
[paramsDic setValue:@"Us" forKey:@"language"];
[paramsDic setValue:@"4.3.12" forKey:@"version"];
[paramsDic setValue:@"1711680146397" forKey:@"timestamp"];

Are you sure of that the data in Post should not be base64 or other encoding ?

I don't think it's problematic but @"Conection" -> @"Connection"? Also, could you ask POSTMAN to generate Objective-C code? It might help to see what's wrong by comparing the codes.

Thank you @NewbieiOS for your reply but I got the solution - it was by public key which I was using for encryption was wrong . Once I changed it , the app works smoothly ,

Thank you  @PtitXav for your reply . It has to be converted .ut8 encoding

Thank you @Larme for your reply .  I corrected the spell mistake and I was using code from postman only and it worked.

POSTMAN code needs to be corrected/adapted, as it's not "beautiful" code (but usually working code).  It's a good thing to help compare and see what's different, and what was wrong. What was the error then?

@Larme : My public key used for encryption was wrong
